# chef resource cloning - what is it?

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to get more information on what chef resource cloning exactly is. I see them during my chef-client run but don’t know what they mean.

I’ve seen this blog below on resource cloning but I still can’t make sense of what it does. Does anyone have further information on this topic? Can’t find much else using google.

http://scottwb.com/blog/2014/01/24/defeating-the-infamous-chef-3694-warning/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that article does a great job of explaining it... What are you confused on?

Comment: say for example i have the following 2 resources

"""service "apache2" do
  action :enable
end """
 and 
"""service "apache2" do
  action :start
end"""

and they are in diff cookbooks. when its cloned does that mean the service that starts apache is lost? or does it merge them?

Comment: resources in recipes would have been merged across cookbooks.  which is highly confusing, spooky action-at-a-distance kind of behavior that is difficult to reason about.  that is why it was removed.

Answer (score 1):

chef-client will merge resource definitions by their type and name (`service[apache2]` in your example). If you're working on wrapper cookbook check this great article: http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right from Julian Dunn.

Anyway, you can modify previously defined resources. In your case:

```
resources('service[apache2]').action [:enable, :start]
```

This will modify already defined resource `service[apache2]` and hide resource cloning warnings.

Comment: i see. so what happens if for example. i have a role and it does the following. recipe1-install-apache -> recipe-2-somechanges_that_also_edit_apache.conf -> recipe3-start apache. in this case if im merging, i lose the sequence i wanted this to run in. I know the request doesnt make any sense but it's really just to understand the theory behind cloning. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

#### Deprecation: [Resource Cloning (CHEF-3694)](https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_resource_cloning.html)

Chef allows resources to be created with duplicate names, rather than treating that as an error. This means that several cookbooks can request the same package be installed, without needing to carefully create unique names. This is problematic because having multiple resources named the same makes it impossible to safely deliver notifications to the right resource.

The behaviour in Chef 12 and earlier, which is now deprecated, is that we will try to clone the existing resource, and then apply any properties from the new resource. For example:

```
file "/etc/my_file" do
  owner "ken"
end

file "/etc/my_file" do
  mode "0755"
end
```

will result in the second instance having the following properties:

```
file "/etc/my_file" do
  owner "ken"
  mode "0755"
end
```

Resource cloning was deprecated in Chef 10.18.0 and will be removed in Chef 13.